# How to generate numeric paging control in wpf

Tags: wpf

please someone share the idea of developing numeric paging control like web pages. which look like 1,2,3....10 Next> and when user will click on the link then a even will fire from where we can bind grid again and also the control will have some property like TotalData, no of data perpage etc. i search google but found nothing so if anyone already developed this type of control in WPF then please share some idea or give me url from where i can get the similar article.......thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links and see if that helps

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Paging.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/8a2ea78b-f1e3-45b4-93ef-32b2d802ae17/wpf-datagrid-custom-pagin.aspx